# Code hitting can't find a fix for it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys i am having my code hitting and its bugging my website

I don't know why but i can't find a fix for it...
my code:

```
            <script>
            $(function() {
                $("div.star-rating > span").on("click", function(e) {
                    var numStars = $(e.target).data("stars");
                    saveVoting('faq', {id}, numStars);
                });
            });

            $('form#formValues').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                saveFormValues('savecomment', 'comment');
                return false;
            });

        </script>
```

The code is hitting here...

```
                        saveVoting('faq', {id}, numStars);
```

> there is a Syntax error on line 155. Code hiting may not work untill you fix this error.

Comment: Hitting? What do you mean by that?

Comment: remove the curly brackets from around `id`

Comment: @vascowhite
there is a Syntax error on line 155. Code hiting may not work untill you fix this error and the line 155 is this: saveVoting('faq', {id}, numStars);

Comment: @SamuelCook
What did you mean by curly brackets from around?

Comment: change `{id}` to `id`

Comment: I think OP means "hinting". p.s. this is javascript (jQuery) not PHP

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where id is defined? The only thing, form this code I can see, is that id is undefined, and the brackets are throwing off the correct returned error.

Comment: why you gave me a negative reputation?